# GLPI plugins not working on virtual host (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed GLPI on a Ubuntu 14.04 server running the latest version of Apache2.  It works fine until I create a virtual host to run GLPI. I'm able to log in, but once I try to hit any of my plugins, I get

```
[Thu Sep 22 10:57:42.016046 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 11162] [client 10.145.0.77:44057] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/glpi/plugins/consumables/consumables.js, referer: http://glpi.domain.com/front/backup.php
```

I've verified through multiple channels that my permissions on my folders are correct, and that my directives are set properly in my .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/glpi/
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
         CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
         <Directory "/var/www/html/glpi/">
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
         </Directory>
         ServerName glpi.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm banging my head here (and I've read all the SO articles about this issue). Advice is welcome.

-Larry

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct but...
You are using "AllowOverride All" which means, any .htaccess file inside any directory under documentroot will override your settings. Set AllowOverride none or check all your .htaccess files, so your virtualhost looks correct but anything can override what you are showing us.

Even more /front is not defined anywhere in the configuration you show, so there must be an alias or something somewhere which points /front but you are not showing it either.

I also noted that the URL in the access log and the one in the VirtualHost ServerName directive, make sure you are configuring/checking the correct virtualhost also.

Comment: re: domain -mean to edit that out :)

no .htaccess files in my subs

Will double-check AllowOverride later this morning. 

Thanks

Comment: i was incorrect.  found some .htaccess files.  working through it now